# Bash comparing STDERR with a string

Tags: bash

I want to get standard error of a command and compare if it contains some string:
I've created this script:

```
SONARQUBE_SCANNER_HOME=/var/lib/sdon
                    if msg=$(/var/lib/dtt 2>&1)
                    then
                    echo "Command has is working fine!"
                    else
                      if [[ "$(echo $msg | grep -i 'No such file or directory')" = 'No such file or directory' ]]
                      then
                        echo "Command Path was not found. Not a code issue! Build will now be UNSTABLE!"
                        exit 0
                       else
                        echo "It is something else"
                      fi

                    fi
~
```

but the ouput is

```
+ SONARQUBE_SCANNER_HOME=/var/lib/sdon
++ /var/lib/dtt
+ msg='test: line 4: /var/lib/dtt: No such file or directory'
++ echo test: line 4: /var/lib/dtt: No such file or directory
++ grep -i 'No such file or directory'
+ [[ test: line 4: /var/lib/dtt: No such file or directory = \N\o\ \s\u\c\h\ \f\i\l\e\ \o\r\ \d\i\r\e\c\t\o\r\y ]]
+ echo 'It is something else'
```

As you can see for some odd reason it splits No such file or directory for no reason.
The end is just to compare the error of the command to some string, but this seems to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if [[ "$(echo $msg | grep -i 'No such file or directory')" = 'No such file or directory' ]]` should be `if grep --ignore-case --quiet 'No such file or directory' <<< "$msg"`:

1. `grep` returns the *whole line*, including the "test: line 4: /var/lib/dtt: " bit, which is not equal to the text you're looking for in the `[[` command. You can use `--only-matching` to print only the part of the line matching the regex.
2. `grep` exits with code 0 if it finds a match.
3. Since you don't need to *print* the match (and to speed up existence checks in larger inputs), you can use `--quiet` to just exit as soon as it finds a match, without printing it.
4. `if` just checks whether the *command* after it returns exit code zero. `[[` is just another command, like `grep`.
5. Long option names (while not available in *all* incarnations of `grep`) make it obvious what the command is doing, rather than obscuring it.
6. You very rarely need to use `echo` (or `cat`, another often abused command) to send things to standard input of commands. A [here string](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) is handy for this case.
7. Finally, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) :)

Comment: That works I wasn't aware of <<< . Can u just elaborate a bit more on how that works and mine doesn't. Would really help to better understand.

Comment: No worries, just added a link to a very good resource.

Comment: Can that worth with regex? For example "No such*"?

Comment: `*` on its own just means "zero or more of the preceding expression," which is just "h". You want `.*` at the end. Regexes are not globs.